# Cost of bitshift and getting bit-sequence from integer

Tags: java, header, bit-shift

I have a 32-bit Integer which represents a header of a file.

**AAAAAAAA AAABBCCD EEEEFFGH IIJJKLMM**

I therefore need to get specific parts of the Integer to find out what value it has. I'm currently getting the bit-sequences by using bitshifts.

E.g.

```
    (HEADER >> 19) & 3;

    (HEADER >> 17) & 3;

    (HEADER >> 12) & 15;

    (HEADER >> 10) & 3;

    (HEADER >> 6) & 3;
```

I'm doing this millions of times, so I need it to be fast.

So my questions are :

Is this the fastest way, or is there a better way?

Is the cost of `Integer >> 1` the same as `Integer >> 20`?

Will it be faster to first make the Integer a String, then get the bit sequences using substring, and finally parsing back to int?

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise operators are implemented using register-level operations. Therefore, they are almost constant time operations (O(1)).
Whereas, the substring operation on Strings is linear time (O(n)).

I would suggest you to stick with the bitwise operations, it's the fastest you can get.